# Como redeclarar uma function depois de carregar novo conteúdo com Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Eu preciso atribuir aos novos elementos carregados através de uma requisição ajax esta function **bloginfos()**. Existe uma forma mais elegante e profissional, no meu código de fazer isso?

```
$("#frm_busca_projetos").on("change", function(){
    var termo = $("#termio").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: CAMINHO_JAVASCRIPTI+'/projetos/ajaxgetprojects',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {termo:termo, categorias:categorias, publicado:publicado, midia:midia},
        success: function(retorno) {
            $("#allinprojects").fadeOut(400, function() {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
                $(this).empty().append(retorno);
                $(this).fadeIn(400);
                bloginfos();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: o que essa função faz? ela é chamada em outro contexto também? não tem nada intrínsecamente errado aí, mas pode ser que existam outros jeitos de conseguir o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Bom dia. Então essa function ativa o clica que executa um efeito nas demais divs de abrir/fechar para mostrar conteúdo.

Comment: não é nada que se resolva com `on()`?